# Where is my 'concepts' library for C++20 concepts?

Tags: c++, stl, c++20, c++-concepts

I can successfully compile code that uses the `concept` keyword, but not anything that includes `<concept>` or `<concepts>`.

```
// #include <concepts> // fatal error: 'concepts' file not found

template<class T>
concept Adds = requires(T a, T b) { a+b; };
template<class T>
concept Subs = requires(T a, T b) { a-b; };
template<class T>
concept AddsSubs = Adds<T> && Subs<T>;
```

Obviously without the library, things like this won't work:

```
template <class X, typename Y>
requires std::constructible_from<X, Y>
// error: no member named 'constructible_from' in namespace 'std'
auto new_unique(Y && y) -> std::unique_ptr<X>;
```

That was slightly modified from a "how to use" page on the `constructible_from` concept.

I'm missing something simple, I'm sure.

I'm using Clang 15 as from the Github (92ab024f81e5b64e258b7c3baaf213c7c26fcf40). When I use G++, I have to replace `-std=c++20` with `-std=c++2a -fconcepts` before it behaves the same (both errors above.)

By the way, when compiling with Clang I don't have `-stdlib=libc++`, this causes it to lose sight of all standard headers. Things like `std::unique_ptr` as above are visible just fine. I believe this is because either my build of llvm was interrupted or I didn't install correctly. However G++ wouldn't be affected by that.

I'm working on Linux but I can move to an online compiler if you prefer. I don't think it's relevant, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: 1. You probably don't have libc++ at all. You need to install it separately. By default, clang++ uses libstdc++ which comes with gcc. 2. You cannot use `<concepts>` because your installation of gcc is too old. Upgrade. 3. Do not, I repeat, **do not**, build your own llvm/clang/gcc. Install from packages.

Comment: There was a reason I moved to compiling my own... the upstream version was significantly out of date and something convinced the maintainer that the more recent versions changed too much to be considered stable. I don't know much about what differs about my platform but it's Xubuntu (Ubuntu with XFCE.) And for what it's worth, I had libc++ but it appears to be version 10. I'll get back to you.

Comment: Ubuntu flavours have various additional repos with more up-to-date toolchains. Try `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test`.

Comment: Also see https://apt.llvm.org/

Comment: I appear to have fixed it, following the instructions you mentioned and several related SO questions... I don't know if I understand well enough to answer my own question, but I would support this question being merged with another that has the same solution. I just didn't know how to phrase the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Ah, just kidding, I had switched everything over to g++ to do sanity checks. Now I'm actually missing `<iostream>`. I guess as long as I can use g++ I'm okay for now, but I'd like to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: If you have a problem with llvm/clang++/libc++ installation ask a question about it. Start with the exact commands you used to install, and the exact command you are using to compile.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't just start to do this, I can't possibly document my steps. There are several versions of clang, llvm, etc., not including the Github version, all installed at different times with varying efforts to override the previous, now with yet another repository in the mix. If it helps any, I followed the instructions you linked at apt.llvm.org verbatim and hunted down outdated symlinks, etc. (cont.)

Comment: I'd like to try to reproduce this in an online compiler but few have C++20, the right version of Clang and the LLVM libraries. At least if I could do that, I could say definitively that my installation is wrong, then compare versions, tweak arguments, and so on to track down the problem incrementally. Without that I don't know where to begin other than "I installed libc++ wrong, maybe, or LLVM or Clang or...." Do you really think this is right for a new question?

Comment: I should have looked more carefully at the invocations. I had `-std=c++20` all right, but `-std=c++17` was in an imported makefile (which put it later in the arguments.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I compiled the following on Godbolt using Clang++ 15 and libc++. It proves that `<concepts>` is visible, that concepts can be applied and used, and that there are no linker errors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <concepts>
#include <typeinfo>

template<class... T> using And = std::conjunction<T...>;
template<class... T> using Or = std::disjunction<T...>;

template<class S, class... T> using Same = And<std::is_same<S, T>...>;
template<class S, class... T> using In = Or<std::is_same<S, T>...>;
template<class S, class... T> using IIn = In<S, std::make_signed_t<T>...>;
template<class S, class... T> using UIn = In<S, std::make_unsigned_t<T>...>;

template<class T> concept IFixed = In<T, short, int, long, long long>{};
template<class T> concept UFixed = UIn<T, short, int, long, long long>{};
template<class T> concept Fixed = IFixed<T> || UFixed<T>;
template<class T> concept Floating = std::floating_point<T>;
template<class T> concept Arithmetic = Fixed<T> || Floating<T>;

void vprint(UFixed auto const& r) { std::cout << "(Unsigned) fixed: "
    << r << " (" << typeid(r).name() << ")\n"; }
void vprint(Fixed auto const& r) { std::cout << "(Signed) fixed: "
    << r << " (" << typeid(r).name() << ")\n"; }
void vprint(Arithmetic auto const& r) { std::cout << "Floating: "
    << r << " (" << typeid(r).name() << ")\n"; }
void vprint(auto const& r) { std::cout << "Non-arithmetic: "
    << r << " (" << typeid(r).name() << ")\n"; }

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    vprint('0'); // Non-arithmetic: 0 (c)
    vprint(true); // Non-arithmetic: 1 (b)
    vprint(-1); // (Signed) fixed: -1 (i)
    vprint(0u); // (Unsigned) fixed: 0 (j)
    vprint(std::size_t{1}); // (Unsigned) fixed: 1 (m)
    vprint(2-1.0e-6); // Floating: 2 (d)
    vprint(""); // Non-arithmetic:  (A1_c)
    vprint(nullptr); // Non-arithmetic: nullptr (Dn)
    vprint((void*)nullptr); // Non-arithmetic: (nil) (Pv)
    flush(std::cout);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/1aG47v39z

That means it's still my installation, and not a problem with C++ or concepts. Not only that but everything works in G++ now, so it's absolutely my Clang or libc++ installation, and Clang reports the right version. All that's left is LLVM and libc++ as far as I know. If I can't figure it out, as [n-1-8e9-wheres-my-share-m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775806/n-1-8e9-wheres-my-share-m) said, I should post a new question.

Update: I removed old versions of Clang, LLVM, etc., reinstalled the new ones, and worked on a few other things, and when I came back to it it compiled. Very frustrating. Accepting this answer seems wrong.

Update 2: I think I found it. `-std=c++20` was fine, but an imported makefile was effectively forcing `-std=c++17` later in the arguments, and I didn't look closely enough after I saw the ones I was looking for. All I was missing was a single question mark and it cost me days.